# display top manager name based on the employee salary

Tags: sql

**emp_name**

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Emp_ID ║ Emp_Name ║ MG_ID ║ EMP_Desg ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║  1001  ║  John    ║       ║ Manager  ║
║  1002  ║  Miller  ║       ║ Manager  ║
║  1003  ║  Ruby    ║ 1001  ║ Employee ║
║  1004  ║  Jack    ║ 1001  ║ Employee ║
║  1005  ║  Mary    ║ 1002  ║ Employee ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

**emp_salary**

```
╔════════╦════════╗
║ EMP_ID ║ Salary ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║  1003  ║  2000  ║
║  1004  ║  5000  ║
║  1005  ║  4000  ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```

How can i get the manager name whose sum of salaries of the employees under that manager is high than any manager.

I want to display John as top

Comment: Please specify dbms used. You've already got a product specific answer - hopefully for the dbms you're using...

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
SELECT en1.MG_ID, en2.Emp_Name, SUM(es.Salary)
FROM emp_name en1 INNER JOIN emp_salary es ON en1.Emp_ID = es.EMP_ID
INNER JOIN emp_name en2 ON en1.MG_ID = en2.Emp_ID
GROUP BY en1.MG_ID, en2.Emp_Name
ORDER BY SUM(es.Salary) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I am assuming you are using MySQL.

Click the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/625fa/2)

Comment: MySQL answer, I assume.

Comment: @jarlh This is what I assume.  I didn't even think to look for the specific RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Let table emp_name as t1 and table emp_salary as t2:

```
Select t1.emp_name, t1.emp_id
from EMP_NAME t1
where t1.emp_id in
    (Select t2.emp_id from EMP_SALARY t2 where MAX(t2.salary))
  AND t1.Emp_Desg = 'Manager%'
```